# if statement inside a loop works. But not after I add the "looped"/'repeated' fetch

Tags: javascript, loops, date, if-statement, fetch

I have posted a similar question earlier, but I was not concise enough.
So, here i go!

I am fetching some data, an array of objects, from a website, and then looping thru it to modify it.
I am modifying it solely because i need new elements inside each object in an array to later run some "if-statements" on them.

I had found that my loop and if statements work okay without the fetch function. However, when I add it, the if statement that should return true does otherwise.

The example code is at the bottom.

This is the part that works outside the fetch if i run it as is (after i get the data array of objects. i ran the code without fetch, and it was all okay.)

```js
if (time < new Date(new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: 'UTC'}))) {
  var time = new Date(new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: 'UTC'}))
  //changing time with current time in UTC if time is "smaller"
} else {
  //do nothing
}

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data[i]['ontime'] = (new Date(new Date(data[i].starttime).toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: 'UTC'})))
  data[i]['estimatedtime'] = dateAdd(new Date(time), 'second', Math.round(data[i].distance.value / 50 * 60 * 60))
  for (let j = 0; j < data.rooms.length; j++) {
    /*push and save some elements*/
  }

  if (data[i].ontime > data[i].estimatedtime) {
    //do something
  } else { // repeat fetch if the condition is false
    console.log('unsuitable!')
    getData()
  }
}
```

I have tried to make two loops.
One for mutating the data array's objects, and the other for if-statements
+I had used asynch/await function for these two separate loops, to make sure 2nd loop (if-statements) starts only after the 1st loop finished. it did not seem to work.
Previously, i posted that the error was with the date, that it was showing 'invalid date'. I fixed that, but i still have the same problem.

```
var errorcheck = []
time = new Date('11/2/2019 14:25')

function getData() {
  fetch(fetch_url)
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        errorcheck.push(response.status)
      } // if response is not ok, i store the error code.
      else if (response.ok) {
        response.json()
          .then(data => data = data)
          .then(() => {
            if (data.length > 0) { // checking if any "data array" has objects
              if (time < new Date(new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone:'UTC'}))) {
                var time = new Date(new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone:'UTC'}))
                //changing time with current time in UTC if time is "smaller"
              } else {
                //do nothing
              }

              for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                data[i]['ontime'] = (new Date(new Date(data[i].starttime).toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: 'UTC'})))
                data[i]['estimatedtime'] = dateAdd(new Date(time), 'second', Math.round(data[i].distance.value / 50 * 60 * 60))

                for (let j = 0; j < data.rooms.length; j++) {
                  /*push and save some elements*/
                }

                if (data[i].ontime > data[i].estimatedtime) {
                  //do something
                } else { // repeat fetch if the condition is false
                  console.log('unsuitable!')
                  getData()
                }
              }
            } else {
              console.log('no object in data!')
              getData() //if data array had no objects inside, i repeat the fetch
            }
          })
      }
    })
}
```

## UPDATE:

I have taken out the next code, and it worked fine with the fetch too.

```
if (time < new Date(new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone:'UTC'}))) {
                var time = new Date(new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone:'UTC'}))
                //changing time with current time in UTC if time is "smaller"
              } else {
                //do nothing
              }
```

**I need this code to run every-time a fetch is run as well. Otherwise, the timestamp (`estimatedtime`) would be totally irrelevant.
i tried making a second `.then` after the 1st and 2nd too. `time` was not updated. Just like `time`(and `estimatedtime` consequently) I have other variables that need to be modified each time a fetch is run or finished.**

Comment: why a `new Date()` wrap of `new Date()`, do not think that is needed, `var time =` you already have a global `time`, perhaps change the name or rethink the logic a bit. `.then(data => data = data)
  .then(() => `  why `then` and another `then`?

Comment: i will try, but i do not think it is gonna make any difference.
like i said when take the fetch out, loops and if-statements work fine and output the expected results.

Comment: disclaimer: I am pretty new to fetch API.
"```.then(data => data = data) .then(() =>``` why then and another ```then```"
i thought that would make sure it waits until the data array is saved and only then runs loops and ifs.

Comment: Like you thought, it seems like the second ```.then``` is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure on your logic desired by here I simply add an element to the document and attach an event and trigger that when more data is needed.

I also created `myApp` to hold the values rather than multiple global variables.

```js
var myApp = myApp || {
  errorcheck: []
};
// these could be in the object above like the errorcheck is
myApp.lastTimestamp = new Date();
myApp.fetch_url = "some/urlthing";
myApp.time = new Date.UTC();

var aNewDivElement = document.createElement("div", {
  id: "newDivElement"
});
var getMoreDataEvent = new Event('getMoreData');
aNewDivElement.addEventListener('getMoreData', function(e) {
  myApp.getData();
}, false);

document.body.appendChild(aNewDivElement);
var divHoldEvents = document.getElementById("newDivElement");

myApp.getData = function() {
  fetch(myApp.fetch_url)
    .then(function(response) {
      if (response.ok) {
        let data = response.json();
        // checking if any "data array" has objects
        if (data.length > 0) {
          myApp.myUtcDateTime = new Date.UTC();
          if (myApp.time < myApp.myUtcDateTime) {
            myApp.time = myApp.myUtcDateTime;
          }
          for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            // seems odd to do these, do we mean the new array?
            data[i].ontime = myApp.myUtcDateTime;
            let est = dateAdd(new Date(myApp.time), 'second', Math.round(data[i].distance.value / 50 * 60 * 60));
            data[i].estimatedtime = est;
            for (let j = 0; j < data.rooms.length; j++) {
              /*push and save some elements*/
            }
            if (data[i].ontime > data[i].estimatedtime) {
              //do something
            } else { // repeat fetch if the condition is false
              console.log('unsuitable!');
              divHoldEvents.dispatchEvent(getMoreDataEvent);
            }
          }
        } else {
          console.log('no object in data!');
          //if data array had no objects inside, i repeat the fetch
          divHoldEvents.dispatchEvent(getMoreDataEvent);
        }
      } else {
        // if response not ok, store the error code.
        this.errorcheck.push(response.status);
      }
    });

};
// start things off 
divHoldEvents.dispatchEvent(getMoreDataEvent);
```